# Real and imaginary part of a vector in the complexification of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $ V $ be a vector space over the real numbers. Suppose all we know about it's *complexification* is that it's a *complex* vector space $ V_{\mathbb C} $ equipped with an $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \iota\colon V\hookrightarrow V_{\mathbb C} $ such that the following universal property holds: for every complex vector space $ F $ and for every $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \phi\colon V\to F $, there exists a unique $ \mathbb C $-linear map $ \tilde\phi\colon V_{\mathbb C}\to F $ such that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>\iota>> V_{\mathbb C}\\
@| @VV\tilde\phi V \\
V @>>\phi> F
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

I want to show that every vector $ v\in V_{\mathbb C} $ can be written in a unique way as
$$
v = v_1 + iv_2
$$
for some $ v_1,v_2 $ in the image $ \iota(E) $ of $ E $ inside $ V_{\mathbb C} $.

Observe that this is a bit different from saying that
$$
V_{\mathbb C}\cong \iota(E)\oplus i\iota(E)
$$
since first of all $ \iota(E) $ is *not* a (complex) vector subspace of $ V_{\mathbb C} $. A fake proof using the universal property of $ V_{\mathbb C} $ as stated above is the following: given any complex vector space $ F $ and any $ \mathbb R $-linear map $ \phi\colon E\to F $, define $ \tilde\phi\colon \iota(E)\oplus i\iota(E)\to F $ just by
$$
\tilde\phi(v_1,v_2) = \phi(v_1) + i\phi(v_2)
$$
and check that $ \tilde\phi $ is unique, q.e.d. Nevertheless this does not give an isomorphism like the one I wrote above, for the aforementioned fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is a standard one. Define $V_\mathbb{C}' = \{\iota(v_1) + i \iota(v_2) \mid v_1, v_2 \in V\} \subseteq V_\mathbb{C}$. It is fairly straightforward to demonstrate that $V_\mathbb{C}'$ is a sub-$\mathbb{C}$ vector space of $V_\mathbb{C}$. Closure under addition and $0$ is clear; closure under complex multiplication is only slightly more involved.

Now note that $\iota$ factors through $V_\mathbb{C}'$. Apply the universal property to produce a unique $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\phi : V_\mathbb{C} \to V_\mathbb{C}'$ such that $\phi \circ \iota = \iota$. Apply the universal property again to conclude that $\phi = 1_{V_\mathbb{C}}$ when viewed as a map $V_\mathbb{C} \to V_\mathbb{C}$. Thus, $V_\mathbb{C}' = V_\mathbb{C}$, so all elements of $V_\mathbb{C}$ can be written as $\iota(v_1) + i \iota(v_2)$.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I just don't understand yet how you get the uniqueness for $ v_1 $ and $ v_2 $ using this trick.